# USB to OBD-II Converter

Tags: usb, microchip, ftdi, can, obd

I want to make a scan-tool that works via a PC for my Thesis. To test it I have bought an ECU simulator ([ECU-Sim 2000](http://www.scantool.net/ecusim-2000.html)) with a CAN bus.

I'm planning to make it using an [FT232H](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232H.htm) USB to serial chip and a [MCP 2515](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21801G.pdf) stand-alone CAN controller followed by a [MCP 2551](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21667f.pdf) high-speed CAN transceiver. I want to be able to send PID requests and get the response messages from the ECU simulator and be able to get information on malfunction events etc.

Are those ICs enough to do the work with a properly designed software, so that this specific simulator (and hopefully actual ECUs) can get the messages I'm sending and properly respond? If not, what additions should I make? I want to avoid using a microcontroller so that the design is cheap to create.

Comment: Will you be open-sourcing your eventual design?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using Both, 2551 and 2515. Though I never used any of them, What I figure out it 2551 takes data from UART and converts it in CAN while 2515 takes data from SPI and converts it to CAN.

And If you don't want to use any Microcontroller, How you will interface SPI based CAN controller to your PC?

I would say, Try once with 2551 as you can directly communicate with this chip via PC (Don't forget Level Shifter like MAX232) and observe output on scope or something. If it works then great otherwise my suggestion would be to use a microcontroller like LPC2129.

It will be easy for you to communicate between CAN and PC using a micro (IMO).

Comment: I only noticed it myself recently but most of the newer FTDI chips like the FT232H do support SPI.

Comment: 2551 is a CAN voltage level converter so its essential. 2515 is a microcontroller that acts as a CAN bus node and is the one creating the complete CAN frames and also extracting the data from a CAN received message. I have already tried a plain 2551 design with an FT232BL playing the role of the usb to serial converter, but it wouldn't work because with this setup I couldn't send a complete CAN frame (usually 8-15 bytes, depending on the data being sent).

Comment: Ohh... Got to learn two new things! :)